# How to pass an object between two independent functions?

Tags: r, function, arguments, environment

I have (for example) the following two functions, and the user chooses if he wants to call first `f1()` and then `f2()`, or call only `f2()` :

```
f1 <- function(a, b) {
  my_sum <- a + b
  return(my_sum)
}

f2 <- function(a, b, c) {
  my_sum2 <- a + b + c
  return(my_sum2)
}
```

If the user first calls `f1()` and then `f2()` he knows he needs the same values he assigned to `a` and `b` when he called `f1()` to be assigned to `a` and `b` when he calls `f2()`. The thing is that if he calles

```
 x1 <- f1(a = 1, b = 2)
```

and provided values to `a` and `b`, next when he calls `f2()` I want to enable him to provide only the `c` argument and not having again the need to insert the same arguments for `a` and `b` he used when called `f1()`.

For example:

```
> x1 <- f1(a = 1, b = 2)
> x1
[1] 3
> x2 <- f2(c = 2)
Error in f2(c = 2) : argument "a" is missing, with no default
```

When he calls `x2 <- f2(c = 2)` I want `f2()` to take the values of `a` and `b` from `x1 <- f1(a = 1, b = 2)`. 
How can I make this happen?
Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Best,

Ayala

Comment: How about `f2 <- function(a, b, c) {if(missing(a) & missing(b) ) x1 + c else a + b + c}
`

Comment: @ExperimenteR, this assumes that x1 is in the global environment which may not be the case (although the sample code above suggests so)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
f1 <- function(a, b) {
  my_sum <- a + b
  a<<-a
  b<<-b
    return(my_sum)
}
```

And for f2 you also need to declare global var(`<<-`)

for example

```
a=0
b=0
f1 <- function(a, b) {
  my_sum <- a + b
  a<<-a
  b<<-b
    return(my_sum)
}
f1(4,4)
[1] 8
f2 <- function(a1=a, b1=b, c) {

  my_sum2 <- a1 + b1 + c
  return(my_sum2)
}
f2(c=3)
[1] 11
```

Comment: This may work here, but is "life beside a volcano" [http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf] (R Inferno, Circle 6)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be helpful for your specific situation, but in general, this is how I get around similar issues:

```
# define a function that returns a vector
f1 <- function( a, b )
{
  my_sum <- a + b
  return(c ( my_sum, a, b ) )
}
# assign the returned vector to a variable for further use
#   and extract the value you are interested in
x1 <- ( xx1 <- f1( a = 1, b = 2 ) )[ 1 ]
x1
[1] 3
xx1
[1] 3 1 2

# use the vector for default values for your 2nd function
f2 <- function( c, a = xx1[2], b = xx1[3] ) 
{
  my_sum2 <- a + b + c
  return(my_sum2)
}

# if f1() was called before, only one argument:
x2 <- f2( 3 )
x2
[1] 6

# or all three arguments in one call
x2 <- f2( 2, 4, 3 )
x2
[1] 9
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Actually I am looking for a solution to this issue in general and the function I gave were only examples to illustrate the problem. However the solution you suggested is not flexible enough mainly because of  this part `x1 <- ( xx1 <- f1( a = 1, b = 2 ) )[ 1 ]`. Thank you again!

Comment: If you are a bit more precise, maybe I can help. Passing only by value and never by reference is a challenge in R, but I got used to it.

Comment: Hey @vaettchen. The only thing I can think of now is the following: If there was a way to extract (within the environment of `f2()`) the values of `a` and `b` from the environment of `f1()` that would be great. Thanks again!